# How to create disabled icons for Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm referencing the official Eclipse guidelines located [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines), which in the section "States" contain the information on "Creating the disabled icon state".

Sadly, the first sentences in this section are:

> To create this state, you will use the "eclipse_disabledrender_R3V6.atn" action in the Eclipse-style Actions palette. Click here to download the Eclipse-style Actions.
>
> 1. Load the "eclipse_disabledrender_R3V6.atn" into the the Adobe Photoshop Actions palette.

I have no Adobe Photoshop, so I have no idea what that file does (I tried opening it as a text file, but it's nothing readable).

The image for this section is not accessible either, so any information on how to create disabled icons is lost (to me).

I assume it's something like "change saturation to -50 and brightness to +50", but I'd love to have the original actions for a consistent look.

How do I create disabled icons for a given icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get myself a copy of Adobe Photoshop, and this is what the action says:

[image]

It's German, so I'll translate the relevant part for whoever might have the same problem:

- Hue 0 (no changes)
- Saturation -80 (scale seems to be -100 to 100, with 0 the default)
- Brightness +40 (on the same scale)

For some reason this action paints a rectangle around the finished icon (RGB 193, 193, 193), but I couldn't find a disabled icon where this was actually done.